# Laravel 5.8 Symlink doesnt link

Tags: php, laravel, storage, symlink

I have one page where everything works fine. I moved this page to another server (not localhost) but my symlink doesnt work. When I upload files, they are stored only in storage/app... but not in public/storage

When I delete folder: public/storage from local and also from server and run: php artisan storage:link it will write The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Also in routes I have *Artisan::call('storage:link');*

In env I have set FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public

filesystem.php:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
                'private' => 0600,
            ],
            'dir' => [
                'public' => 0775,
                'private' => 0700,
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

view:

```
 <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->full) }}" id="brandLogo" class="img-fluid" alt="img">
```

Code should be ok because at the other site I have the same code and it works. I have Laravel 5.8

Can you help me please?

Comment: just update your `root` in the `public` array to `'root' => 'storage'`

Comment: and try to upload images again after edit it

Comment: is it secure to link it storage folder which is not in public folder?

Comment: i try alot to make the command `storage:link` in the server as you try but with nothing happen

Comment: 'root' => 'storage': it created new folder in storage folder: storage/storage but didnt help

Comment: I also tried <?php
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
?>

It didnt help too

Comment: make sure that you change the file driver from your `env` file like this `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public`

Comment: How should I change it? I have FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public. It should be ok

Comment: add `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public` to your `env` file if you don't

Comment: I have it in `env`

Comment: it should now work fine, if not delete your `storage` folder in your `public` and create an empty one because it may still point to your real storage

Comment: But url of picture is pointing to public/storage :( With this solution I cant use asset, can I?

Comment: could you show me the URL that saved in image in you database ?

Comment: I dont store the whole URL in database, only file name and its linked to the product by foreign key.

Comment: you can use `url` instead of `asset`

Comment: That is true. Thanks, I am going to sleep. Maybe somebody will write solution to make symlink work. I will do it tomorow.

Comment: if this answer helped you feel free to vote it, and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your `root` **path** in your public 'array'
to be

```
'root' => 'storage'
```

but in this case, you can't use `asset` to print the path so you will be using `url` instead

so it would be like this

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/'. $image->full) }}">
```

about security, it's full **secured** if you try to go your storage from url like this

```
localhost/storage
```

it will give you access denied